# Spring how to make password on admin panel

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have spring security with 2 roles (ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN).
Now, I want to implement admin panel. I have already done access to panel url only for users which have ROLE_ADMIN. But I want to make extra secure.
When user with ROLE_ADMIN open admin panel pages first time, he will have to enter a admin panel password. So, my question is What the good way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested idea, by making user with role 'ROLE_ADMIN' re-enter his password is used to secure in case of leaving your device unlocked. It used for critical high potential actions like changing your mail password, which require something like token renewal. I think implementing Two-factor authentication add a second security layer.

Comment: I don't want a two-factor authentication. I have common authentication for all users does not matter is this user admin or no. And I just want to add feature for entering different second password for admins when they trying to log in admin panel.

Comment: Okay, i got it. I've two ideas. I hope be helpful for you. The first one is inspired from Two-factor authentication, the multiple token principle. Make your admin panel page requires a multiple token, when the admin user enter the second password grant the second token to him. The second idea is inspired from  'Decorator Pattern'. It is about decorating your admin user, when the user enters the second password, logout the user admin, and login the decorated user admin with user-admin full authority, plus admin panel authority.